# r.in.xzy not found in QGIS 3.16.1 with GRASS 7.8.4

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I am running QGIS 3.16.1 with GRASS 7.8.4 and I am unable to find the `r.in.xzy` raster function within GRASS.

My aim is to count the number of points falling into each of the cells of a raster layer. Is any replacement of the `r.in.xzy` function?

I have tried most of them but it seem that most similar one works only for las files.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the `r.in.xyz` module is missing in QGIS Processing since you must first define the raster resolution before doing the input of an xyz file. (The Processing framework creates a new, temporary GRASS environment for each module run, and prepares the extent and resolution based on input layers, and this would not work for `r.in.xyz`)

Why not run the module directly in GRASS??